# java: Optimizing if statement in Java using Optional

Tags: java, java-8

I have the following code in Java which I need to optimize by the usage of Optional in Java 8:

```
if (x.isEmpty() || x.contains("<")) {
   x = "hello1";
}
else if (x.contains(",")) {
   x = "hello2";
} else {
   x = "hello3";
}
```

Can someone suggest a Java 8 based code using Optional?

I don't want to use multiple if-else. I prefer using something more functional like `Optional` in java 8 since if-else is more imperative style. So I can correct and say my objective is not in terms of code optimization in terms of performance, but making it use Java 8 standards which are more functional in nature.

Comment: Code looks perfectly readable and performant to me. What are you hoping for in terms of  'optimization'?

Comment: I don't want to use multiple if-else and using something more functional like Optional in java 8 since if-else is more imperative style.  So, I can correct and say my objective is not in terms of code optimization in terms of performance, but making it use java 8 standards which are more functional in nature

Comment: Code is perfect as is. `Optional` is not meant to replace `if`/`else` blocks, but to be used as the return value of methods that might return a result or not. Using `Optional` as you desire is considered an antipattern. At least, by Stuart Marks, who is the lead developer behind `Optional` https://youtu.be/Ej0sss6cq14?t=1665

Comment: And adding method calls to code that already works without them cannot possibly be described as `optimization`. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    x = x.isEmpty() || x.contains("<") ? "hello1" 
            : x.contains(",") ? "hello2" : "hello3";
```

If you’re after the functional style that you can in some cases have with `Optional`, then you still don’t need an `Optional` in this case, but rather the good old conditional operator (sometimes called the ternary operator; it was there since Java 1.0). There would be no meaningful way to fit an `Optional` into your code.

Comment: It would even fit into one line

Answer (score -4):

I have tried this approach. It is making your code more cleaner and Object-oriented . This pattern can be used when there is lot of if/else block which leads to confusion. Hope this is what you are looking for.

```
package com.test;

import java.util.Optional;

public class Refactor {

String x;

public Refactor(String x) {
this.x = x;
}

Optional<String> condition1() {
    if (x.isEmpty() || x.contains("<")) {
           return Optional.of("hello1");
        }
    return Optional.ofNullable(null);
}

Optional<String> condition2() {
    if (x.contains(",")) {
           return Optional.of("hello2");
        }
    return Optional.ofNullable(null);
}

public String  conditionTest() {
    Refactor refactor = new Refactor("ab<cd");
    if(refactor.condition1().isPresent()) {
        return refactor.condition1().get();
    }
    if(refactor.condition2().isPresent()) {
        return refactor.condition2().get();
    }
    return "hello3";
}
```

}

Comment: Besides needing ten times the code, this answer is not even showing, how to avoid the two `if` statements in the main method. Evaluating `condition1` or `condition2` two times in a row, and calling `isPresent`, followed by `get`, is not how an `Optional` is supposed to be used. Use `orElseGet​` and `orElse` to address the actual question. Besides that, using a `main` method with a string array argument, but being non-`static` and non-`void` return type, is confusing the readers for no benefit.

Comment: The question asked to get rid of the two `if` statements. You’ve got four instead.

Comment: This answer needed discussion but surely down vote is unfair. Accepted answer by @Ol

Comment: My answer needed discussion but surely down vote is unfair. Maybe I failed to express my intent. Accepted answer by @OleV.V. uses a turnery operator which becomes very shabby when number of conditional check increases. 
Advantage of my code is if/else pair gets converted to if block. Reading 10 if block is way much cleaner and better understandable then 10 if/else block. It became possible only due to Optional class and Encapsulation design principle.

Method parameter in the initial code was unnecessary, I have refactored that.

Comment: I didn’t downvote and am not going to. Opinions differ as to whether the answer is useful, and users who think it isn’t may help other users of the same opinion by downvoting. Also unfair and inexplicable downvotes are part of life on Stack Overflow. They always hit me when I least expect it, but they don’t hurt in the big picture. See if you can take it rather as an amusing sign of differences than as a harm being done to you.

Comment: "They always hit me when I least expect it, but they don’t hurt in the big picture" . Agree with you. It hit me hard this time, but rightly said its part of big picture. Thanks.